# SQlite Android no such table columns students.studentId

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I think I almost spend my time searching in the web for the possible solution to my problem. I successfully inserted a student and a subject but when getting the data from the two tables, it will cause to crash the program and display an error "no such columns".

Please help me.

Creating tables

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SUBJECT = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_SUBJECT + "(" + SUBJECT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + SUBJECT_NAME
        + " TEXT," + SUBJECT_SCHEDULE + " TEXT," + SUBJECT_FILELOCATION
        + " TEXT" + ")";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_STUDENT = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_STUDENT + "(" + SUBJECT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + STUDENT_NAME
        + " TEXT" + ")";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_FUSION = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_FUSION + "(" + FUSION_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + SUBJECT_ID
        + " INTEGER," + STUDENT_ID +" INTEGER" + ")";
```

My query for displaying data from two tables

```
public List<Student> getAllStudnetsBySubject(long id) {
    List<Student> subject = new ArrayList<Student>();


    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_STUDENT + " students, "
            + TABLE_SUBJECT + " subjects, " + TABLE_FUSION + " fusions WHERE subjects."
            + SUBJECT_ID + " = '" + id + "'" + " AND subjects." + SUBJECT_ID
            + " = " + "fusions." + FUSION_ID + " AND students." + STUDENT_ID + " = "
            + "fusions." + FUSION_ID;



    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Student s = new Student();
            s.setStudentId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(STUDENT_ID))));
            s.setStudentName((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(STUDENT_NAME))));
            subject.add(s);


        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return subject;
}
```

LOGCAT ERROR

```
02-27 07:00:32.938: E/DatabaseHelper(20727): SELECT  * FROM student students, subject subjects, fusion fusions WHERE subjects.subject_id = '1' AND subjects.subject_id = fusions.id AND students.student_id = fusions.id
02-27 07:00:32.948: E/SQLiteLog(20727): (1) no such column: students.student_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String EntryA =String.valueOf( db.getentry("Ravirrrr", "KEY_Team_Name"));
```

Change this to

```
String EntryA =String.valueOf( db.getentry("Ravirrrr", "_Team_Name"));
```

`KEY_Team_Name` is a variable in your sqlite helper the value of which contains the column name `"_Team_Name"`. You don't want the literal string `"KEY_Team_Name"`.

Comment: Yes, use the values `"_Team_Name"` or refer to it in your sqlite helper and make the variable there public.

Comment: Your cursor is empty. Check the result of `moveToFirst()` before any of the `get...()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you didn't add `student_id` to `student` table:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_STUDENT = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_STUDENT + "(" + SUBJECT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + STUDENT_NAME
        + " TEXT" + ")";
```

You need to modify it and add it:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_STUDENT = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_STUDENT + "(" + STUDENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + SUBJECT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + STUDENT_NAME
        + " TEXT" + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like you made a simple copy-and-paste mistake. Change this:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_STUDENT = "CREATE TABLE "
    + TABLE_STUDENT + "(" + SUBJECT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + STUDENT_NAME
    + " TEXT" + ")";
```

To this:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_STUDENT = "CREATE TABLE "
    + TABLE_STUDENT + "(" + STUDENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + STUDENT_NAME
    + " TEXT" + ")";
```

In other words, just change SUBJECT_ID to STUDENT_ID.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you were writing code for Student table you copy the code from Subject table and modify it but you forgot to modify the Subject_ID column to Student_ID. That's why it is giving error that Student_ID is not present in the Student table. Use following updated code,

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_SUBJECT = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SUBJECT + "(" 
        + SUBJECT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
        + SUBJECT_NAME + " TEXT," 
        + SUBJECT_SCHEDULE + " TEXT," 
        + SUBJECT_FILELOCATION + " TEXT" 
        + ")";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_STUDENT = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STUDENT + "(" 
        + STUDENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"  // Change here 
        + STUDENT_NAME + " TEXT" 
        + ")";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_FUSION = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FUSION + "(" 
        + FUSION_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
        + SUBJECT_ID + " INTEGER," 
        + STUDENT_ID +" INTEGER" 
        + ")";
```